# Where is context getting passed in?

Tags: dart, flutter

Consider the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Text('Hello World'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My understanding of Buildcontext is that it is the "context" of the widget (please correct me if I'm wrong or elaborate further). What I don't understand is how is the argument "context" passed into the method. Does the runApp function supply the "context"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR: *This is controlled by the framework*.

For those who like reading:

Starting from the very beginning. The `runApp` method takes your app widget and inserts it into the tree, as per comment on the method ([binding.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/6c049ec28678f73992298811f79041e1fcd9bf65/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart#L674)):

> Inflate the given widget and attach it to the screen.

When that's being done, the app `StatelessWidget` (which obviously is a `Widget`) is being inflated into an `Element` (`Widget` class comments in [framework.dart file](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/6c049ec28678f73992298811f79041e1fcd9bf65/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L350))

> Each time a widget is placed in the tree, it is inflated into an
>   [Element], which means a widget that is incorporated into the tree
>   multiple times will be inflated multiple times.

If you then have a look at the abstract class `Element`, in the same GitHub repo file ([framework.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/6c049ec28678f73992298811f79041e1fcd9bf65/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L2428)), you will see the comments above it, saying:

> Elements have the following lifecycle:
>
> - The framework creates an element by calling [**Widget.createElement**]
>     on the    widget that will be used as the element's initial
>     configuration.
> - The framework calls [**mount**] to add the newly created
>     element to the tree    at a given slot in a given parent. The [mount]
>     method is responsible for    inflating any child widgets and calling
>     [attachRenderObject] as    necessary to attach any associated render
>     objects to the render tree.

These two methods `createElement` and `mount` are the ones that are responsible for calling the `build` method.

If you have a look at the the `StatelessWidget` class, you will see that it has an override for `createElement` method ([framework.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/6c049ec28678f73992298811f79041e1fcd9bf65/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L550)). Which creates `StatelessElement` object and passes itself (`this`) as a constructor parameter. Notice, how the `StatelessElement` class overrides the `build` method and calls `widget.build`method (in this case, the `widget` is your app widget - i.e. `MyApp`). This still doesn't tell us how the `build` method is called though. If you drill down a bit deeper, into the `ComponentElement` (class that `StatelessElement` derives from - [framework.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/6c049ec28678f73992298811f79041e1fcd9bf65/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L3589)), you can see the `mount` method being overridden. In this method (which is invoked by the framework), there's a call to `_firstBuild` method, which then calls `rebuild`, this method then calls `performRebuild` method, which finally ends up invoking the `build` method.

Easy, right?

**DISCLAIMER**: This is just me connecting the dots. I'm not an expert on Flutter - I literally started using Flutter a week ago. It would be good if some more experienced devs could confirm or not, if my understanding of the mechanisms behind widgets is correct.

EDIT: Answering comment questions

1. Inflating (in my mind) is creating the object in the memory (so that framework has a reference of it) and rendering it on the screen.
2. Yes, the `BuildContext`is going to be the `StatelessElement`, which contains a reference to the app itself

[image: Debugging with VS Code - Flutter Redux architecture sample]

Comment: This is a very good detailed attempt at explaining this for just one week of using flutter!  I have 2 questions, please bare with me I am new to mobile app development in general. 1. Does inflating mean instantiating an object (our widget in this case), 2. From your explanation it seems that this Element object (hopefully I am saying that correctly) is actually our BuildContext, am I correct in saying this?